# Why I got getText is not a function in a protractor test?

Tags: protractor

Im testing with protractor 7.0.0 and got the next error with the next code:

`it('Translation', function () {
        var transButtonText = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="menubar"]/status-bar/div/div[2]/button/div'));
        expect(transButton.getText().toBe('ES'));
    });`

error: `Failed: transButton.getText(...).toBe is not a function`

I don't know why I got this error, I should get the text without problems, right?

Comment: Do you have SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER on or off? Also make sure you have grabbed the element properly before asserting something. If your `element` failed silently (for some reasons) then you are basically calling `.getText()` on `undefined`

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket for your expect. .toBe is called on `expect` but you are attempting to call it on `getText()`. Your statement should read `expect(transButton.getText()).toBe('ES')`